# select a column value from a table only if it has a value assigned else insert a user defined value into that column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

my requirement is to generate a mysql query as

```
select ss.column1 P1,ss.column2 P2,ss.column3 P3 from table1 ss;
```

i want to select column 2 field values only if it has a value in table1 else i want to insert a constant value into the P2 column. Can someone help me with framing a query for this.

Comment: You don't want to insert missing values into your table, but only select values from it, right? And in case column2 is empty you want to show a default value for it, yes?

Comment: Please give some input data and give the data of what you are Expecting (or) Post Query whatever you Tried Then only someone able to answer your Question.

Comment: Which of the two DBMS are you actually using, MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: Yes @ThorstenKettner you are absolutely right and thats what i wanted to ask. Sorry for not being clearer in my words.

Comment: Thanks everyone guys :) it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` is the SQL function that let's you replace null values by something else. E.g.:

```
select 
  ss.column1 as p1,
  coalesce(ss.column2, 'no value') as p2,
  ss.column3 as p3 
from table1 ss;
```

The data types must match however, so you can use the above when column2 is a text column. If it is numeric, you can replace null with a numeric value (e.g. with a zero) or you'd cast the columns' datatype.

Some examples:

```
coalesce(mytext, 'unknown')
coalesce(mynumber, 0)
coalesce(cast(mynumber as varchar), 'unknown')
coalesce(mydate, date(now()))
coalesce(date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m-%d'), 'unknown')
```